# Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 255

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

When I write to the console any firefox related command it throws an error.
Input:
$ firefox
Output:
Exec failed with error: Permisson denied.

And when I run the python code I get an error:
Webdriver Exception:Process unexpectedly closed with status: 255

Help me, pls :)

Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/local/bin/firefox'    
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=600,1200")
```

Comment: Hello!
Please: you need post fully reproducible console commands that caused you trouble and fully reproducible python code(including concrete package dependencies) whenever you want concrete technical help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you have execution permission on the firefox binary from the user executing the console command.